# Backslash sequence doesn't match

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to have a word boundary within a negative lookahead. However, as you can see in the example below this does not appear to work in Python. Is this unsupported? If so, is there a way workaround?

To state the full problem I am trying to solve: I have a regex that I'm using in `re.sub`, and there are a couple specific words (like "455") that I want to specifically not match.

```
In [8]: print re.match('(?!455)455', '455')
None

In [9]: print re.match('(?!455\b)455', '455')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1108fb440>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` is an escape sequence, and as such it will match the backslash character ASCII `0x08`. You need to escape the backslash or use [raw string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
>>> print(re.match(r'(?!455\b)455', '455'))
None
```